# OpenGL ES 2.0 Context in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm new to OpenGL on Android and I have read heavily documented samples, and I kinda understand it. But before trying to do anything complex, I want to draw a simple 2D white rectangle on a black bacground. Nothing else.

I'm stuck at this error: `call to OpenGL ES API with no current context`, which seems to be that I'm calling something from the non-OpenGL `Thread`. The thing is that I'm not sure what is called from the OpenGL `Thread`. So here's my code

//============== Activity ==================//

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

MyGLSurfaceView surface;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    );

    surface = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(surface);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    surface.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    surface.onResume();
}

}
```

//==================== GLSurfaceView ========================//

```
public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

MyGLSurfaceRenderer renderer;

public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

    renderer = new MyGLSurfaceRenderer(this);
    setRenderer(renderer);
}

}
```

//================== Renderer ==========================//

```
public class MyGLSurfaceRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

Square square = new Square();

public MyGLSurfaceRenderer(MyGLSurfaceView surface) {

}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    square.draw();
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

}

}
```

//==================== Square ========================//

```
public class Square {

private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;

// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
static float squareCoords[] = { -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
                                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
                                 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
                                 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f }; // top right

private short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices
float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f };


private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_Position = vPosition;" +
        "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
    "precision mediump float;" +
    "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
    "}";

int mProgram;

static final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;
static final int vertexCount = 4;

public Square() {
    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(squareCoords.length * 4); // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(drawOrder.length * 2); // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);


    int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables
}

public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

    // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

    // add the source code to the shader and compile it
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
}

public void draw() {
    // Add program to OpenGL ES environment 
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                                 GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                 vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

    // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    int mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

    // Set color for drawing the triangle
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

    // Draw the triangle
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
}
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem may be this line:

```
Square square = new Square();
```

Because it gets initialized before the call to "setRenderer". The constructor for Square calls GLES20 methods, which could be causing the problem. Try instantiating it after the call to "setRenderer(render);" or inside the "onSurfaceCreated" method.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thanks