# libgdx throws error on spritebatch creation

Tags: java, android, libgdx, kryonet

If I change the screen like this it works.

```
        button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
               someclass.setScreen(someclass.getGameScreen());
           }
        });
```

But my goal is to use a server response to change the screen like this:

**Main.java**

```
        button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
               client.sendTCP(new ChangeLobbyToGameRequest());
           }
        });
```

and

```
    public void changeToGame(){
        someclass.setScreen(someclass.getGameScreen());
    }
```

**Server listener**

```
if (object instanceof ChangeLobbyToGameResponse){
        Main.changeToGame();
 }
```

but then I get the following error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
Process: com.somegame.game, PID: 15828
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error compiling shader: 
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.createDefaultShader(SpriteBatch.java:164)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.<init>(SpriteBatch.java:127)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.<init>(SpriteBatch.java:81)
    at com.labyrix.game.Screens.GameScreen.show(GameScreen.java:46)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
    at com.labyrix.game.Screens.Lobbyscreen.changeToGame(LobbyScreen.java:59)
```

**Gamescreen show method**

```
@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    isorend = new Board(batch);
    ..... 
}
```

Comment: Slightly extended, the error message should be:

E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

It's worthy to look after this error message. Read e.g. this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807857/opengl-es-2-0-context-in-android

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL operations have to be carried out on the main thread. In the case of the button, the `clickListener` is called on the UI thread (or called main thread) so fine. However, in the case of the server response its a different thread. So you need to transpose the server callback to the main thread

```
public void changeToGame(){
        Gdx.app.postRunnable (new Runnable() {
           someclass.setScreen(someclass.getGameScreen());
        });
}
```

`postRunnable` is queued on the main thread satisfying openGL requirements.